# How to do a simple username search query using JPA

Tags: java, jpa

i am trying to get the user to search for a username and output the results, i think i have everything almost there i am just unsure if i am doing this correctly and using the right classes;

currently i have in the view

```
<p:inputText id="search" value="#{bean.userToDelete.getUsername}"  />   
                <p:commandButton value="Search" action="#{bean.searchUser}" update="group" />
```

which should allow the user to enter a search term

this then goes to the "bean" which is a controller
this is currently all i have

```
public void searchUser() {
    }
```

but in my UserService (which is in my business layer) i have

```
public String usernameSearch(String username) {
        List<User> usernameSearch = this.userFacade.usernameSearch(username);
        return "/index";
    }
```

which i think should be able to search the db ?

however  also have a UserFacade bean with

```
   public List<User> usernameSearch(String searchString) {
        Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT u FROM USERS U WHERE u.username = :search");
        q.setParameter("search", searchString);
        return q.getResultList();
    }
```

i suppose my question is have i got all the things i need to run a search query and how can i put them all together to make it work ?

sorry i am new to this as the method i was using to do all this turned out to be wrong and the aim is once i can understand how this works i will be able to be do more but it is just understanding how the proccess works atm

Comment: Do you use spring for IoC?

Comment: no, just the jpa and derby stuff that comes with netbeans it is for a jsf application

Comment: SELECT U FROM USER U WHERE U.username=:search shouldn't both the "u" declared and used be same??

Comment: That code was auto generated by netbeans when i first created it

Comment: Is this causing an issue ?

Comment: I just dont know how to call it to run

Answer (score 1):

JPQL uses entity and field/property names. It NEVER uses table and colum names. And class, field and alias names are case sensitive just like Java is.

Your query should thus be:

```
select u from User u where u.name = :search
```

(assuming the mapped field or getter is `name`/`getName()`)

Comment: Hi there thanks, how would i call this from the user interface and where in the MVC would this go ?

Comment: The way you have it is OK, except the UserFacade should be named UserDAO or UserRepository: it isn't a facade.